# Salesforce IDP, OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow

Tags: apex, oauth2, single-sign-on, connected-apps, identity

I'm trying to use Salesforce as an IDP for Aha! Ideas Portal.

I had the SAML working fine, but now I need to setup JWT.
I'm currently following these tutorials: [Using JSON Web Token (JWT) for Aha! Ideas Portal single sign-on (SSO)](http://support.aha.io/hc/en-us/articles/203636345) and [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm)

I currently have the settings done in Ideas and I've set up a connected Apps in Salesforce.

However, I currently get a grant type not supported, when I try to access the login page.

From the Network resources I have:

1. Goes to myaccount.ideas.aha.io (GET/302)
2. Open a new portal_session (GET/302)
3. Recognize that I use jwt so redirect to mycommunity/services/oauth2 (GET/400 - Invalid)

From my understanding I should be creating a JWT Bearer Token because based on the Ideas doc:

1. Your application recognizes that it has received a JWT authentication request.
2. Your application authenticates the user.
3. Your application builds a JWT response and redirects the user back to your ideas portal including the JWT response.

I found this article, An Apex implementation of the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow, but wanted to know if some people had other successful experience on building such authentication flow on the Apex side with other connected Apps.

Thanks,